# Set default selected value in extjs6 comboBox

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have made code like below

```
Ext.define('Abc.store.Indicator', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.indicator',
    fields: ['key', 'value'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'array'
        }
    },
    data: [
        ["ALL", "ALL"],
        ["Y", "Y"],
        ["N", "N"]
    ]
});

Ext.define('Abc.view.main.Indicator', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    xtype: 'indicator',
    fieldLabel: 'Ind',
    name: 'indicator',
    displayField: 'value',
    valueField: 'key',
    store: {
        type: 'indicator'
    }
});
```

and in report items i use like

```
 items: [{xtype:'indicator'}]
```

When user opens the report, i want 'N' to be displayed as default value. How do i do this. I set 'value' key, but when dropdown is opened, selected value is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can put `queryMode: 'local'` in the config of '`Abc.view.main.Indicator`', or the store will load.

Here is the key code *classic/classic/src/form/field/ComboBox.js line 1562*

```
    if (lastSelected && selectionModel.selected.length && store.indexOf(lastSelected) > -1) {
            itemNode = lastSelected;
    }
```

So the new Store doesn't has the lastSelected which you set.